# Is the Map $i$ a Complete or Dense Embedding from Prikry Silver forcing $\mathbb P\mathbb S$ to Sacksforcing $\mathbb S$?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Is the following map $i$ a complete embedding or a dense embedding from the Prikry-Silver forcing $\mathbb P\mathbb S$ to the Sacks forcing $\mathbb S$?
\begin{align}
 i \colon \mathbb P\mathbb S \to \mathbb S: p \mapsto \{s : s \in 2^{<\omega}, \text{$p \cup s$ is a function}\}
\end{align}
where $\mathbb S := \{T : \text{$T$ is a subtree of $2^{<\omega}$}, \text{$T$ is perfect}\}$, $\le_{\mathbb S} := \subseteq$, $\mathbb P\mathbb S := \{p : \text{$p$ is a function}, \mathrm{dom}(p) \subseteq \omega, \mathrm{ran}(p) \subseteq 2, \lvert \omega \setminus \mathrm{dom}(p)\rvert = \aleph_0 \}$, $\le_{\mathbb P\mathbb S} := \supseteq$

Any contribution, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Here's an "abstract nonsense" style argument, at least assuming CH. Both Sacks and Prikry–Silver reals are minimal, but Sacks reals also have the property that for any *new* real is actually generic for the Sacks forcing (namely, there's an automorphism which maps the canonical Sacks real to a name for that fixed new real).

So, if the map was a complete embedding, it would mean that any Sacks real adds a Prikry–Silver real is actually a Sacks real in disguise. Which is something we know isn't true.

---

More concretely, though, note that a condition in the Prikry–Silver forcing translates to a "uniformly perfect" tree, where for any $|s|=|t|$, both in $T$, the extension $s^\frown i$ is in $T$ if and only if $t^\frown i\in T$, for $i\in\{0,1\}$.

Now, start with a perfect tree and recursively prune it in a way that is non-uniformly perfect. That is not very hard, and it shows more directly that this embedding is not dense and not complete.